# Invalid Procedure call or argument for concatentaion

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error while running the vba script in MS-Excel

> Invalid Procedure call or argument

Following is my code

**Code**

```
Sub FindValues(ByVal WhereToFind As Range, ByVal WhereToPaste As Range)
    'where to find should have the header and values
    Dim col As Integer  'loop through columns
    Dim row As Integer  'loop through rows
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim b() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    a() = WhereToFind

    For row = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    For col = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
        If a(row, col) = "X" Then
          i = i + 1
          ReDim Preserve b(1 To i)
          b(i) = a(1, col) & "=" & a(row, 1)
        End If
      Next
    Next
    WhereToPaste.Resize(UBound(b)).Value = Application.Transpose(b()) // getting error on this line
End Sub
```

**Caller Method**

```
Sub caller()
FindValues ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E4"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any cells containing `"X"` in the range B2:E4?  (I get the error if `b` is still an undimensioned array.)

Comment: yes i have X from b2:e4

Comment: (a) Insert a `Debug.Print b(1)` just before the line causing the problem, and see if the code crashes (with a "subscript out of range" error) on the `Debug.Print` line.  (b) Do you have `"X"` or `"x"`?  (i.e. are they uppercase, or lowercase)

Comment: I will print the debug and I have value as "X"

Comment: `Application.Transpose(b)`

Comment: @Slai - `Transpose(b())` works just as well for me

Comment: or do you have formulas in the source range

Comment: no source range and Transpose(b()) is not working for me

Comment: (a) Did you get an error when the code got to the `Debug.Print` or did it print something in the immediate window?  (b) You could try placing a `Dim b(1 To 1): b(1) = "No matches"` just before the start of the first loop. and then see whether the code writes `"No matches"` to cell F1

Comment: I did that but it did not work for me so please let me know is there any way for doing it

Comment: You will get that error when your array `b()` is empty, (no matches found for `"X"`).  Add some `Debug.Print UBound(b)` before the error line and check it out.

Comment: how can i debug the values can you help me into debugging the values